# Upon booting, wifi won't work until disabled and re-enabled

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

After booting Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, I am not able to connect to Wifi, until I disconnect and reconnect.  This has been happening for a while but I am finally getting tired of reconnecting after a boot, so Im trying to fix it. In my efforts to troubleshoot here is what I have so far:

- When Wifi is not working I can not ping local network addresses
- I get the same behavior logged in as a different user
- Changing IPv6 settings to "ignore" has no effect, despite `IPv6 Configure Timeout` (see log below).
- Here is what I get from `grep Network /var/log/syslog` when the Wifi is not working :

  ```
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): using nl80211 for WiFi device control
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): new 802.11 WiFi device (driver: 'iwlwifi' ifindex: 3)
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): now managed
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): bringing up device.
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): preparing device.
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
  NetworkManager[1132]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/lxcbr0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> wpa_supplicant started
  NetworkManager[1132]:        SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lxcbr0, iface: lxcbr0)
  NetworkManager[1132]:        SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lxcbr0, iface: lxcbr0): no ifupdown configuration found.
  NetworkManager[1132]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/lxcbr0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: ready -> inactive
  NetworkManager[1132]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
  NetworkManager[1132]:        SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/virbr0, iface: virbr0)
  NetworkManager[1132]:        SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/virbr0, iface: virbr0): no ifupdown configuration found.
  NetworkManager[1132]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/virbr0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'Skylab'.
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'Skylab'
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'Skylab' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'Skylab'
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'Skylab'.
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> dhclient started with pid 2157
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> reboot
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info>   address 192.168.2.9
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info>   gateway 192.168.2.1
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.2.1'
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info>   domain name 'Belkin'
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> DNS: starting dnsmasq...
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): writing resolv.conf to /sbin/resolvconf
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: ip-config -> activated (reason 'none') [70 100 0]
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Policy set 'Skylab' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) successful, device activated.
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
  ```

  The rest is only present when Wifi is not working:

  ```
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> DNS: starting dnsmasq...
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): writing resolv.conf to /sbin/resolvconf
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: ip-config -> activated (reason 'none') [70 100 0]
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Policy set 'Skylab' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) successful, device activated.
  NetworkManager[1132]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
  ```
- Here is the info on my wireless card from lspci -v :

  ```
  08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000
  Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
  Memory at d1d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
  Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
  Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
  Capabilities: [e0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
  Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
  Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 74-e5-0b-ff-ff-7d-3a-38
  Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
  Kernel modules: iwlwifi
  ```

Not sure where to go with this, any help is appreciated, including tips on troubleshooting.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I think it happens when I was connected to university network where I have to use VPN before. If I get home I have the same problem as you. The other way around I can't even select my VPN from the menu until I disable and enable my wifi adapter. If I was in other networks without VPN there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same OS, same issue, but setting IP6 to "ignore" worked for me. Maybe you have to relog for it to take effect?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the known power management issue with the iwlwifi driver. If so, then the problem does not occur when the laptop is plugged in to power.

Look for similar problems at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bugs?field.searchtext=iwlwifi

Comment: The problem does occur when plugged in to power.